# Magento, how to rewrite index.php in url ? (nginx)

Tags: magento, nginx, php

I have problem about rewrite rule index.php in magento.

Ex.
    domain/indoor.html is 500 internal server error but
    domain/index.php/indoor.html is can display.

```
    My nginx.conf is 

    user  root;
    worker_processes  1;

    error_log   /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

    events {
         worker_connections  1024;
         multi_accept on;
         use epoll;
    }

http   {
index index.html index.php;
include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
default_type  application/octet-stream;

log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';                   

server_tokens       off;
sendfile            on;
tcp_nopush          on;
tcp_nodelay         on;


## Gzipping is an easy way to reduce page weight
gzip                on;
gzip_vary           on;
gzip_proxied        any;
gzip_types          text/css application/x-javascript;
gzip_buffers        16 8k;
gzip_comp_level     8;
gzip_min_length     1024;

##  SSL global settings
#ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:15m;
#ssl_session_timeout 15m;
#ssl_protocols             SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
#ssl_ciphers               AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:RC4:HIGH:!MD5:!aNULL:!EDH;
#ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

keepalive_timeout   10;

## Nginx will not add the port in the url when the request is redirected.
#port_in_redirect off; 

## Multi domain configuration
#map $http_host $storecode { 
   #www.domain1.com 1store_code; ## US main
   #www.domain2.net 2store_code; ## EU store
   #www.domain3.de 3store_code; ## German store
   #www.domain4.com 4store_code; ## different products
#}

##   Add www
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    return 301 $scheme://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {   
    listen 80;
    #listen 443 ssl;
    server_name 192.168.85.114;
    root /var/www/html;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access_192.168.85.114.log  main;

    if ($http_user_agent = "") { return 444;}

    ####################################################################################
    ## SSL CONFIGURATION

       #ssl_certificate     /etc/ssl/certs/www_server_com.chained.crt; 
       #ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/certs/server.key;

    #################################################################################### 
    ## Server maintenance block. insert dev ip 1.2.3.4 static address www.whatismyip.com

    #if ($remote_addr !~ "^(1.2.3.4|1.2.3.4)$") {
        #return 503;
        #}

    #error_page 503 @maintenance;   
    #location @maintenance {
        #rewrite ^(.*)$ /error_page/503.html break;
        #internal;
        #access_log off;
        #log_not_found off;
    #}

    ####################################################################################
    ## 403 error log/page

    #error_page 403 /403.html;
    #location = /403.html {
        #root /var/www/html/error_page;
        #internal;
        #access_log   /var/log/nginx/403.log  error403;
    #}

    ####################################################################################
    ## Main Magento location

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @handler;
    }

    ####################################################################################
    ## These locations would be hidden by .htaccess normally, protected

    location ~ (/(app/|includes/|/pkginfo/|var/|errors/local.xml)|/\.svn/|/.ht.+) {
        deny all;
        #internal;
    }

    ####################################################################################
    ## Protecting /admin/ and /downloader/  1.2.3.4 = static ip (www.whatismyip.com)

    #location /downloader/  {
        #allow 1.2.3.4;  allow 1.2.3.4;  deny all;
        #rewrite ^/downloader/(.*)$ /downloader/index.php$1;
    #}
    #location /admin  {
        #allow 1.2.3.4; allow 1.2.3.4; deny all;
        #rewrite / /@handler;
    #}   

    ####################################################################################
    ## Images, scripts and styles set far future Expires header

    location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
        open_file_cache max=10000 inactive=48h;
        open_file_cache_valid 48h;
        open_file_cache_min_uses 2;
        open_file_cache_errors off;
        expires max;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    ####################################################################################
    ## Main Magento location

    location @handler {
        rewrite / /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ .php/ { ## Forward paths like /js/index.php/x.js to relevant handler
        rewrite ^(.*.php)/ $1 last;
    }

    ####################################################################################  
    ## Execute PHP scripts

    location ~ .php$ {
        add_header X-UA-Compatible 'IE=Edge,chrome=1';
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        #try_files $uri $uri/ @handler;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        ## Store code with multi domain
        #fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_CODE $storecode;
        ## Default Store code
        fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_CODE default; 
        fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_TYPE store; ## or website;
        include        fastcgi_params; ## See /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;

        if (!-e $request_filename) { 
            rewrite / /index.php last; 
        }
    }
}
```

}

but this can't rewrite index.php, please kind your help to solved that for me please.

Answer (score 4):

You're creating a loop by doing another try_files inside what should be the final location. I'll amend my answer with an example when I'm behind a desktop.

Ok, so the nitty gritty on getting nginx to work with Magento. First you have an issue with your denies:

```
location ~ (/(app/|includes/|/pkginfo/|var/|errors/local.xml)|/\.svn/|/.ht.+) {
```

The /pkginfo/ shouldn't include a leading slash and it safest to use /. instead of naming .svn and .ht specifically: if you ever switch to Mercurial or Git, you don't want those accessed either. As a side note - for nginx .ht is not necessary.

You're missing /lib/ and that's the reason I usually split the denies in two:

```
location ~ ^/(app/|includes/|pkginfo/|var/|errors/local.xml|lib/|media/downloadable/) { deny all; }
location ~ /\. { deny all; }
```

Notice that the first one is anchored at the beginning. This is necessary for /lib/ because /js/lib/ is a valid path that needs to be open and without anchoring to the start of the request uri, it will match and your visitors won't be able to load the JavaScript libraries.

Handling the rewrites:

First, the base location. Set the index, try the uri's and define a handler as catch all.

```
location / {
    index index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ @handler;
}
```

In the handler, rewrite everything to index.php:

```
location @handler {
    rewrite /   /index.php;
}
```

Lastly, process php files. We do a final check for existing php file if try_files didn't catch it, then split the path info and pass the params. We also set the MAGE_* variables based on a variable $store, if a multistore is in effect. How to map these, you've already started with in your config, so I won't repeat it:

```
location ~ \.php(/.*)? {
    if (!-e $request_filename) {
        rewrite / /index.php last;
    }
    expires off;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.*\.php)(/.*)?$;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
    fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_CODE $store;
    fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_TYPE "store";
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

And that's it. Hope it helps.

Comment: @Melvin Hey, any idea how to do this when magento does not reside at the root? My current setup is a Magento installation living in domain.com/mage and multiple actual shops living in domain.com/shop1 /shop2 (with the index.php modified to run the website and the rest just symlinked to /mage).

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably at the `@handler` location,  did you write it on your own or was it on the magento docs ?

I'd suggest trying  `rewrite ^ /index.php$request_uri;`

Comment: your suggest still cannot solved this problem.

Are you sure this problem is at the @handler ?

Answer (score -3):

you should edit your httpd.conf file

in linux try to add this code in 
/etc/apache2/apache2.conf   file

```
<Directory "/var/www/magento">   // Path for your site
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Comment: Sorry, I use nginx not apache.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with Slowpache.

Comment: While the answer might be correct for Apache, this question is _clearly_ about `nginx`, so this answer is irrelevant to the OP.